# TLP will not let my battery charge

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery, thinkpad

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 on Lenovo Thinkpad w540. I have installed TLP and played with the battery charge thresholds. I have installed the acpi-call-dkms package to support the charging thresholds. But when I plug in the charger the battery is stuck at whatever charge it had. It will not charge anymore. I am attaching all the relevant information about my configuration. Please let me know if you need anything more specific.

This is when the charger is not plugged in:

```
--- TLP 1.0 --------------------------------------------

+++ ThinkPad Battery Features
tp-smapi   = inactive (unsupported hardware)
tpacpi-bat = active

+++ ThinkPad Battery Status: BAT0 (Main / Internal)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = SANYO
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = 45N1779
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design             =  99470 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full                    =  89260 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now                     =  54420 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =  22369 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Discharging

tpacpi-bat.BAT0.startThreshold                              =     15 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT0.stopThreshold                               =     95 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT0.forceDischarge                              =      0

Charge                                                      =   61.0 [%]
Capacity                                                    =   89.7 [%]
!
!
```

This is happening when plugged in:

```
--- TLP 1.0 --------------------------------------------

+++ System Info
System         = LENOVO ThinkPad W540 20BGCTO1WW
BIOS           = GNET84WW (2.32 )
Release        = Ubuntu 17.10
Kernel         = 4.14.13-041413-generic #201801101001 SMP Wed Jan 10 10:02:53 UTC 2018 x86_64
/proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.14.13-041413-generic root=UUID=d44e67d9-e678-43c1-8fdd-4a8ba00cbbfa ro quiet splash i915.modeset=1 nouveau.modeset=0 i8042.nonpnp=1 vt.handoff=7
Init system    = systemd v234
Boot mode      = UEFI

+++ TLP Status
State          = enabled
Last run       = 10:55:31 AM,     14 sec(s) ago
Mode           = AC
Power source   = AC
!
!
--- TLP 1.0 --------------------------------------------

+++ ThinkPad Battery Features
tp-smapi   = inactive (unsupported hardware)
tpacpi-bat = active

+++ ThinkPad Battery Status: BAT0 (Main / Internal)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = SANYO
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = 45N1779
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design             =  99470 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full                    =  89260 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now                     =  52630 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =      0 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Unknown (threshold effective)

tpacpi-bat.BAT0.startThreshold                              =     15 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT0.stopThreshold                               =     95 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT0.forceDischarge                              =      0

Charge                                                      =   59.0 [%]
Capacity                                                    =   89.7 [%]
```

This is my configuration:

```
--- TLP 1.0 --------------------------------------------

+++ Configured Settings: /etc/default/tlp
TLP_ENABLE=1
TLP_DEFAULT_MODE=AC
TLP_PERSISTENT_DEFAULT=0
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_AC=0
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT=2
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_AC=15
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT=60
CPU_MIN_PERF_ON_AC=20
CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_AC=60
CPU_MIN_PERF_ON_BAT=0
CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_BAT=30
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC=0
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT=1
NMI_WATCHDOG=0
ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_AC=normal
ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_BAT=powersave
DISK_DEVICES="sda sdb"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="128 128"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="128 128"
DISK_SPINDOWN_TIMEOUT_ON_BAT="180 180"
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC=min_power
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT=min_power
AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_TIMEOUT=15
PCIE_ASPM_ON_AC=powersave
PCIE_ASPM_ON_BAT=powersave
WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=off
WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=on
WOL_DISABLE=Y
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC=0
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=1
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER=Y
BAY_POWEROFF_ON_AC=0
BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT=0
BAY_DEVICE="sr0"
RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=auto
RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=auto
RUNTIME_PM_BLACKLIST="10de:11fc"
RUNTIME_PM_DRIVER_BLACKLIST="nouveau nvidia"
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1
USB_BLACKLIST_BTUSB=0
USB_BLACKLIST_PHONE=0
USB_BLACKLIST_WWAN=1
RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=0
DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP="bluetooth wifi"
DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_BAT_NOT_IN_USE="bluetooth wifi wwan"
START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=15
STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=95
DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_LAN_CONNECT="wifi wwan"
DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_WIFI_CONNECT="wwan"
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue the charge seems to be stuck at 59 instead of going to 55 and the back to 80. My `BAT0/status = Idle` don't know if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 6):

Your actual threshold settings tell the battery controller to not charge when AC connected and charge level is between 15% and 95%. Currently your battery has 59%, so it works as designed and configured.

You may reset the thresholds temporarily with

```
sudo tlp fullcharge
```

or choose a more appropriate start threshold as explained in the [FAQ](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html#battery)
or remove the thresholds completely by commenting the two config lines.

Comment: I have commented the setting in the config file but no effect. I purged the acpi-call-dkms package and still no effect. The problem is not that the battery charge is in the configured range, but that it will not charge. I went for lunch right now and had left the AC plugged in, but the charge is still 59%. Also I don't know if this is normal behavior but look at this: /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Unknown (threshold effective).

Comment: +1 I've wondered about this myself but not enough to investigate.

Comment: When I check the status of my system using sudo tlp-stat --battery the battery status shows unknown. This is after commenting the 2 lines in the config file and purging the acpi-call-dkms package.
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Unknown

Charge                                                      =   59.0 [%]
Capacity                                                    =   89.7 [%]

Comment: After reading the linerunner.de page about TLP, I learned that you can temporarily set your charge to the upper threshold. So for example, if your threshold is [40 60], and your battery is at a level between the two, you can use the command sudo tlp chargeonce. This will raise the lower threshold to upperthreshold - 4 so that it will begin charging. What I am confused about is what is happening to your battery when you are in the configured range? I do not see the battery level drop even by one percent while plugged in? How can this be true?

Comment: Your answer makes sense linrunner. I feel dumb today.

Comment: With a Dell based Skylake laptop on Ubuntu 16.04 running: `sudo tlp fullcharge` results in: `Error: ThinkPad extended battery functions not available.`